# How do I add an emissions node to a material with a mixed shader?

Tags: modeling, glass, shader-nodes, reflection

I am making a scene where there are curtains behind a window and lights are supposed ot emit through the curtain and be seen through the window. The issue im having is that the glass is too reflective and not transparent, is there a way to reduce reflectiveness and increase transparency. If I look straight at the window I can see the curtain fine, the angle is causing issues. ive attached my reference as well as my test render as we and the glass material node.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try reducing the IOR (incidence of refraction) - the default 1.45 is for glass but I find it's more suited for curved glass - for flat glass, you can go closer to 1.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett that worked! thanks!